# Elasticsearch inconsistent query results with analyzed string

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a property **edApp.name** I query with match. I have confirmed that the mapping for is "type": "string" so it should be analyzed.

When I query with match, I get a different number of hits each time.

I see the same behaviour whether querying all documents with /_search or a subset through a read alias.

Newer update: A dynamically mapped field seems to be the culprit. The field is **generated.edApp.name** and it gets dynamically mapped with "not_analyzed". As soon as a document with this field is indexed, the analyzer for **edApp.name** breaks and I start seeing the weird results with match queries.

---

document:

```
{
  @context: "http://purl.imsglobal.org/ctx/caliper/v1/Context",
  edApp: {
    name: "ReadingRainbow"
  }
}
```

mapping:

```
"dynamic_templates": [
          {
            "string_theory": {
              "mapping": {
                "index": "not_analyzed",
                "type": "string",
                "doc_values": true
              },
              "match": "*",
              "match_mapping_type": "string"
            }
          },
          {
            "i_dont_know_you": {
              "mapping": {
                "enabled": false
              },
              "match_mapping_type": "object",
              "path_match": "*.extensions.*"
            }
          }
   ],
   "properties": {
        "_all": {
          "enabled": false
        },
        "_timestamp": {
          "enabled": true
        },
...
      "edApp": {
        "properties": {
           "name": {
              "type": "string"
           }
        }
     }
}
```

query returning inconsistent results:

```
{
  "query": {
      "match": {
          "edApp.name": "ReadingRainbow"
      }
   }
}
```

hits.total values when running query multiple times: [44, 56, 57, 69]

term query returning inconsistent results:

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "should": [
            {
                "term": {
                    "edApp.name": "ReadingWonders2.0"
                }
            }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

hits.total values when running term query multiple times: [21, 33, 34, 46]

Other term query returning inconsistent results (note lower case):

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "should": [
            {
                "term": {
                    "edApp.name": "readingwonders2.0"
                }
            }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

hits.total values when running term query multiple times: [44, 56, 57, 69]
NOTE: these are the same counts we saw with the match query!

query with both terms:

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "should": [
            {
                "term": {
                    "edApp.name": "readingwonders2.0"
                }
            },
            {
                "term": {
                    "edApp.name": "ReadingWonders2.0"
                }
            }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

hits.total values are consistent: 79 results

As you can see, the inconsistent hits from lowercase, and camelcase term searches add up to 79 documents. Could the analyzer be creating this inconsistency?

I am using AWS Elasticsearch Service ES 1.5.2

Comment: You should probably show both of your queries and a sample document that you think should match

Comment: updated with examples

Comment: Post the complete mapping of that index, not only one field.

Comment: Complete mapping is 4000 lines. Updated to include dynamic templates I am using. But I dont think they affect anything since the property is explicitly mapped.

Comment: What is the complete search command? (including the index/indices being hit)

Comment: Also, what ES version is this? The index/indices in question - how many primary shards and how many replica shards?

Comment: Are you using any `preference` in the query or routing?

Comment: ES 1.5.2. I see this behaviour when querying all documents with /_search (or a subset through read alias). No preference or routing.

Comment: It seems like the issue is related to enabling doc_values. If I roll back to a mapping without doc_values I no longer see this behaviour. Not sure why this happens since doc_values aren't enabled for analyzed string

Comment: The part I'm most interested into is the different `hits` you get. How many primary shards and how many replicas do you have for this index? Are you querying one index or multiple?

Comment: Single index, 3 primary, 3 replica. I just tried ?preference=_primary and that seems to actually stop the issue from happening. So maybe replica shards are somehow not analyzing the field the same??

Comment: Thank you :-). Your query is hitting a different shard copy every time you run it. And you get 4 different results because you have four different copies of the same data (the primary shard and the three replicas).

Comment: Now the question is why the results are different on those copies, if they have the same data (theoretically). The scores can be different, I'm not worried about that. The `hits` part is the one I'm worried.

Comment: shouldn't the replicas be consistent with the primary? Sometimes I get zero results!

Comment: They should, yes. What's the story with this index and cluster? Did you have issues with the cluster or the nodes? Timeouts, cluster being `red` or `yellow` etc?

Comment: A quick fix for the inconsistency is to set the replicas count to 0 and then back to 3. But this won't explain why they are not in-sync.

Comment: It seems like some documents are analyzed differently on the primaries. Running "query with both terms" with only one or the other of the terms gives different results. I would expect the "ReadingWonders2.0" to return nothing if it is being properly analyzed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121112/discussion-between-smashbourne-and-andrei-stefan).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A dynamically mapped property called **generated.edApp.name** was conflicting with the **edApp.name**.

**edApp.name** was *explicitly* mapped as "analyzed"

**generated.edApp.name** was *dynamically* mapped as "not_analyzed"

Once the dynamically property exists, the match query for **edApp.name** breaks.

My workaround is adding a dynamic template to handle my fields that share names with my explicitly mapped analyzed strings

```
"dynamic_templates": [
          {
            "analyzed_string_theory": {
              "mapping": {
                "index": "analyzed",
                "type": "string"
              },
              "match_pattern": "regex",
              "match": "^.*name|.*keywords|.*description$"
            }
          },
      {
        "string_theory": {
          "mapping": {
            "index": "not_analyzed",
            "type": "string"
          },
          "match_mapping_type": "string",
          "match": "*"
        }
      },
     ... 
]
```

Comment: Fyi I am not able to reproduce the behavior you see, even when using ES 1.5.2. If you want to investigate this further provide a gist with a complete list of commands and the result of those commands starting from the command that creates the index till the command that proves the two different analyzers are used for the same field.